# _Journey Data View query only listing Journeys with a VersionNumber of 1

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, data-views

I've been attempting to join up a query between the _JourneyActivity and _Journey data views on VersionID but am noticing that I am unable to successfully Join up on anything beyond a VersionNumber of 1.

If I query _Journey in Query studio I am able to confirm that it is only listing journey versions with a VersionNumber of 1.

EG

```
SELECT 
JourneyStatus,
JourneyName,
LastPublishedDate,
JourneyID,
ModifiedDate,
VersionID,
VersionNumber,
CreatedDate
FROM _Journey
```

Is anyone able to confirm? This is kind of a showstopper for our purposes. We'd like to filter on Journey Name but right now we're only seeing the first version of the journeys from a _JourneyActivity perspective.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to follow up with the response I received from support.

> This is a known issue that we are aware of. I will have to toggle a
> setting on our backend and it should solve your issue.

So please raise a case if this issue is impacting you.